# Ring having infinitely many zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does there exist a ring having infinitely many zero divisors ?

Comment: It's kind of a duplicate, because every infinite ring with zero divisors has infinitely many of them. It shouldn't be that hard to find *some* infinite ring with zero divisors.

Answer (score 7):

Try $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ :

> $\quad (a,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$ for all $a$

or $M_2(\mathbb R)$ :

> $\quad \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 } \cdot \pmatrix{ 0 & 0 \\ y & 0 } = 0$ for all $y$

Comment: how do you hide your answer , what's the command?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal, see *Spoilers* in http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help.